# Regex to evaluate, but ignore certain characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

I apologize for my regex noobiness, but I can't figure out how to create a regex that would ignore certain characters.

```
var foo = "123",
    bar = "1 (234) a12-34a1",
    result = bar.replace(new RegExp(foo,"ig"),"bcd");
```

If the regex ignored [\s()-], the result should be

```
"b (cd4) abc-d4a1"
```

Is there a way to do this?

UPDATE:

Here's the context of the problem: I have to accept string of numbers, find it in a telephone number (displayed in a variety of ways), and then highlight it in the telephone number.

Normally, I'd just do a simple replace, such as:

```
var foo = "foo",
    str = "foobar",
    newStr = str.replace(new RegExp(foo,"ig"),"<span class='highlighted'>" + foo + "</span>");
```

But the the formatting gets in the way of that.

Examples:

searchStr -> expected output

123 -> **1 (23**4) 567-8901

345 -> 12**3-45**67

56789 -> 123 (4**5) 678-9**012

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: The expected result is in the question. (not sure if that's what you're asking.

Comment: I'm thinking the only way to do this is to strip ignored characters from evaluated string and then re-insert them in the appropriate places after the .replace().

Comment: sorry about my answer, please ignore it if you read it before I deleted it. It ignores all, not certain, characters. sigh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
var foo = "1([\\s()-]*)2([\\s()-]*)3",
    bar = "1 (234) a12-34a1",
    result = bar.replace(new RegExp(foo,"ig"), "b$1c$2d");

result; //b (cd4) abc-d4a1
```

Comment: Would arguably be cleaner if you separated the ignored chars, and then joined them in. But either ways, it's ugly, but what do you expect from regex.

Comment: hmm...doesn't exactly work for me: http://regexr.com/3abj0 but it works in the console, so whatever...

Comment: @Markasoftware Different regex flavors require different chars to be escaped/positioned differently. It works with the usual Js regex as far as I see.

Comment: oh, ok. Got it @plalx

Comment: @Nit, Yeah well I felt a bit lazy ;) Something like `replaceRx = flexibleRegExpFrom('123', '[\\s()-]')` would definitely be better. Further abstractions could be made, but we would need to know more about the OP's domain and use case. He could also write his own replacer without using regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks, plalx! Your solution teaches me a lot, but it looks like it wouldn't be flexible as far as the original search string length. Context for my problem has been edited into the question.

Comment: @KevinChung You could just adapt this solution to dynamic replace lengths.